# What are the supported office UI fabric versions for each SPFx versions?

Tags: spfx, react, 2019, office-ui-fabric-react

It is so confusing that some parts of office fabric will not work as expected with different SPFx versions.

I have created a SPFx solution for SharePoint 2019 on-Premise. Following things are not working as expected so far:

- Multi check box
- Dialog styles

Can anyone tell me what are the supported versions of office fabric UI for each SPFx frameworks starting from 1.4.0.

Comment: Which version of SPFx you are using?

Comment: I have installed 1.8 in dev machine

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, SPFx 1.8 version supports Office fabric react 6.156.0. Try using it.

Comment: My target SP version is 2019 onprem. so 1.8 will not work

Comment: Ok. For SP 2019, try using SPFx 1.4.1

Comment: Yes already doing that from long time

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant, but this is the version I am using:

1. SPFX version: **1.4.1**
2. Office UI Fabric React: **office-ui-fabric-react@5.21.0**

Use Yeonman in order to install the template for SPFX on premise.
Afterwards use the following command:

```
npm install office-ui-fabric-react@5.21.0 --save
```

That should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

> We recommend that you use the versions of the Office UI Fabric React package included in the project in the SharePoint Framework's Yeoman generator. For instance, the SharePoint Framework v1.7.0 release uses Fabric React v5.131.0
>
> **Note**: Fabric React versions 2.x or older are not supported in SharePoint Framework.

**Source**: [Office UI Fabric React](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/office-ui-fabric-integration#office-ui-fabric-react).

Also, SPFx 1.8 supports Office fabric React 6.156.0.

**Source**: [SPFx 1.8 now supports Office Fabric React 6.156.0](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2019/03/14/spfx-1-8-now-support-office-fabric-react-6-156-0.aspx).

There are some changes in usage of the Office UI Fabric icons in SPFx components as mentioned, [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/office-ui-fabric-integration#usage-of-the-office-ui-fabric-icons-in-spfx-components).

Also, you can check below Release notes of SPFx and Fabric React and check their typescript compatibility if that helps you.

**References**:

1. [SharePoint Framework Releases](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs#sharepoint-framework-releases).
2. [Fabric React Demos](https://fabricweb.azurewebsites.net/oufr/).

Comment: What about SP 2016 / SPFx v 1.1? The Yeoman generator did not add _any_ Fabric React dependencies into the scaffolded package, it _only_ adds a dependency of Office UI Fabric Core v 1.4.

Comment: The link titled "Fabric react Demos" has examples that go back only as far as version 6.  I realize this post was in 2019, but are there any pages that have examples that include version 5?